# composite key in google cloud datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

In GCP Datastore & I've a kind with 3 properties.

1. key (auto-generated)
2. externalId
3. externalName

I can't allow duplicate externalName + externalId combination. Is it possible to maintain this uniqueness?

Answer (score 2):

Options:

1. Do what Robert said in his answer, although you would want to using the concatenation of `externalId` & `externalName` as the key. The only downside of this is if `externalId` or `externalName` change, then you wouldn't be able to change your key. You'd have to delete the current object and make a new one; which could have cascading impacts on any other object with key properties that point to this object.
2. Check for `Model.query(Model.externalId== externalId, Model.externalName == externalName).count(1) > 0` before you save. Downside here is that fetching a key is strongly consistent, but queries are eventually consistent. This means if 2 threads submitting the same pair at the same time would both succeed.
3. Save the unique combo in a key, but in a separate table called `Unique`. Here's an example from `webapp2`'s source code where they did just that. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/master/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.py#L33

Comment: Right now, I'm doing the 3rd option but wondering about the reason for this limiation. Dynamo does it OOB

Comment: What inconveniences did you find with the 3rd option? You could file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) if you think that the workaround is not good enough.

Comment: This feature was requested back in 2008, but the datastore team said they weren't going to implement it:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35875869#c14 . I find it a little inconvenient because using web application code to implement database features is inherently fragile. You could by-pass it by mistake.

Comment: Ruben C - its not about the inconvenience. It's a basic requirement,all the suggestions are all workarounds not solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Datastore doesn't enforce constraints like this.  In this case the closest you can get is yo use 'externalId' as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Use `externalId + <some delimiter> + externalName` as the key.

Eg : `externalId:externalName`, `externalId|externalName`  etc..